# How to set KeyEvent to KeyCode.BACK_SAPCE in JavaFx?

Tags: javafx, keyevent, keycode

I'm trying to set `KeyEvent` `KeyCode` to `KeyCode.BACK_SAPCE` if entered value is not a digit.

But I'm not able to achieve it

```
public void textFieldKeyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
     if (!e.getCode().isDigitKey()) {
     textField.setText(""); //manually set text
     e.getCode() = KeyCode.BACK_SPACE; //required: variable found: value
    }
}
```

> I want to remove a character if it is not a digit.
>
> I've assigned `KeyCode.BACK_SAPCE` to `KeyEvent e` but doesn't work.

Hot to use `KeyCode` (s)?

I manually set `textField.setText("");` but want to make use of `KeyCode`

Comment: why? and what do you expect to happen in that line of code? Note that code (as nearly all values of KeyEvent) is read-only.

Comment: I want to remove KeyEvent KeyChar if it is not a digit.

Comment: I tried using `if (!e.getCode().isDigitKey()) {
            txtField.setText("");
            e.consume();
        }` but how to use `KeyEvent.BACK_SPACE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to prevent any non-digit chars from being added to the `TextField`? There is actually a much better way of doing this: use a `TextFormatter` that prevents any changes that result in text that isn't desired. This works much better with copy&paste ect.. You can even implement logic for fixing a change, e.g. removing any non-digit chars from in case of copy&paste.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    TextField digitsOnly = new TextField();
    TextFormatter formatter = new TextFormatter((UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change>) change -> {
        if (change.getControlNewText().matches("\\d*")) {
            return change; // allow change without modifying it
        } else {
            return null; // don't allow change
        }
    });
    digitsOnly.setTextFormatter(formatter);

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(digitsOnly));
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```